# replace elements to reformat the dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

I am trying to parse a genotype data, essentially to convert it for other software to use, sorry if the question is too specific, but any comments and suggestions is greatly appreciated.

```
ID, exp, control
1, aa, bb
2, ab, aa
3, ab, -
```

I would it transformed like this:

1. repeat each column but the first one.
2. The replace `'aa'`, `'bb'` as `'a'`, `'b'`, when it is `'ab'` the first one will be replaced as `'a'`, the duplicated will be replaced as `'b'`.

For example

```
    ID exp exp control control
    1 a a b b
    2 a b a a
    3 a b 0 0
```

I somehow managed to achieve the first goal, but I found the printout is a bit odd, and all of the replacements were not executed:

```
ID exp   exp     control
     control

1 aa     aa  bb
     bb

2 ab     ab  aa
     aa

3 ab     ab  -
     -
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

inputfile = open("test.txt", 'r')
outputfile = open("solomon.txt", 'w')
matchlines = inputfile.readlines()

for line in matchlines: 
        line_parts = line.strip() #strip the end space
        line_parts = line.split(',') #split the line
        output_parts = []
        for part in line_parts[1:]:  #start from 2nd element, so 1st column not duplicate

            if part == 'aa':
               part = part.replace('aa', 'a')
            elif part == 'bb':
               part = part.replace('bb', 'b')
            elif part == '-':
               part = part.replace('-', '0')
            elif part == 'ab':
                 '''the original one will be replaced with 'a' the duplciatd on will be replaced as 'b' '''
            else:
                 print 'Nothing is matched'
            output_part = part + '\t' + part #duplicate each element (1st goal)             
            output_parts.append(output_part) #populate the line      
            line = '\t'.join(output_parts)   #join elements in the line with a tab                
        outputfile.write(line_parts[0] + line + "\n")

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a separate function for this, making it easier to develop and test separately from the other elements.

```
def process_line(line_parts):
    out = line_parts[:1]
    for part in line_parts[1:]:
        if part == "-":
            out.extend('00')
        else:
            out.extend(part)
    return out
```

This gives, e.g.

```
>>> process_line(['1', 'aa', '-'])
['1', 'a', 'a', '0', '0']

>>> process_line(['1', 'ab', 'bb'])
['1', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

You can easily make this a space-separated string with `str.join`:

```
>>> " ".join(['1', 'a', 'a', '0', '0'])
'1 a a 0 0'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, could you explain a bit why my replacement did not work?

Comment: It's hard to tell, please review your question to match the indentation in what you're running.